# Using ActionController::Live is sleep required?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, phusion

I followed the [Rails reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Live.html) to stream some data to the client.

Is the Sleep necessary since I have seen the usage of Sleep everywhere? Does Rails internally use Sleep in Live to stream data?

Comment: Did my answer address your question? Would you like any additional info at all?

Answer (score 0):

The `sleep` function in Rails is used to provide a delay of a specified length of time. In the case listed it looks like `sleep 1` is providing a short pause (roughly one second) after each iteration in your loop, following

```
response.stream.write "hello world\n"
```

So it's not exactly necessary, but it will serve to space the output across a smoother time-frame, rather than having the whole lot output at once.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I have seen the streaming to fail sometimes when the `sleep` is not there. This is seen when we are streaming lots of data. The it failure is manifested for the process to hang and streaming stops. 

If I add the `sleep` with any value the streaming happens smoothly without any issues.